# MySQL event to copy table data into other table before deleting

Tags: mysql, events

I have a table which needs to delete row entries older than 1 hour.
But, before deleting, I want to copy those entries into another table.

I have written event to delete the rows which are older than 1 hour.

How do I copy/update those rows into another table before deleting ?

```
CREATE EVENT deleteUsers
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 600 SECOND
DO 
DELETE FROM userlist WHERE (created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 3600 SECOND AND id >=0);
```

Comment: Create `trigger` for this

Comment: before `DELETE` add a `INSERT` query, and wrap both in `BEGIN ... END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to make use an intermediate table, `userlist_temp`, which has the same table structure as `userlist`, but only exists to hold somewhat temporary data.  After creating this table, you may modify your event as:

```
CREATE EVENT deleteUsers
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 600 SECOND
DO
  BEGIN
    -- take a snapshot of the last hour's records
    DELETE FROM userlist_temp;
    INSERT INTO userlist_temp (col1, col2, ...)
    SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM userlist WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND id >= 0;

    -- remove the records from the last hour from the userlist table
    DELETE FROM userlist u1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM userlist_temp u2 WHERE u2.id = u1.id);

    -- insert the same records which were deleted into your other table
    INSERT INTO other_table (col1, col2, ...)
    SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM userlist_temp;
  END
```

The perhaps roundabout way of using a third intermediate table is to ensure that the records inserted into your other table are precisely the same records which are deleted from the `userlist` table.  By taking a snapshot from the last hour, we can guarantee consistency.

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE userlist_temp;` rather ?

Comment: @Cid Actually, given that `userlist_temp` might be needed every hour in perpuity, it might make performance sense to keep it around.